# How can I fill bottles from a keg and maintain pressure

Tags: techniques, bottling, carbonation, kegs

I've been kegging for awhile now, but I still haven't managed to successfully fill bottles from my kegs without losing all pressure.

I don't have a counter pressure beer filler or a Blichmann Beer gun, and for the moment I'd rather spend my beer-money on something else.

The few times I've tried to fill a couple bottles I've done this:

1. Chill the keg (well, already done)
2. Chill the bottles
3. Turn down the keg pressure to almost nothing, like 1-2 psi
4. Raise the keg
5. Insert a piece of bottle-length tubing over my cobra picnic tab
6. Slowly fill
7. Cap

I'll leave the bottle in the fridge, then come back a couple hours later (or bring it to a friend's house, etc) and the beer has almost no carbonation. My capper seems to work fine, as my regularly bottled beers don't seem to lose any pressure.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [BMBF!](http://www.homebrewtalk.com/f35/we-no-need-no-stinking-beer-gun-24678/)  Get a racking cane and a stopper and you're all set.  I bottle regularly from kegs using this method and it works great.

Comment: This is how I do it as well. Still something of a PITA compared to pulling a pint, but sometimes homebrew needs to be portable.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing; it works great.

Answer (score 2):

Counter pressure and beer gun aside. I think you might want to up the pressure. ALso you can get a stopper to run through and squeese it to let a little pressure to let the beer in but keep it pressurized.

Answer (score 1):

Use normal pressure, don't fill *too* slow, then fill them so a little foam starts pouring over, then cap right onto the foam.  Wipe the beer off the bottle after.

Comment: I tried that first, and it ended up being almost all foam for the last 1/4 of the bottle.

Answer (score 1):

Your method looks correct.   You may want to overcarbonate the beer by 2-5 PSI, and raise the keg pressure to around 5 PSI when bottling.   Slightly overcarbonating will help ensure that there's still a good amount of CO<sub>2</sub> in suspension after you lose some from the bottling process.  You may need to play with the keg pressure a little to balance bottling speed and foam production.

Answer (score 0):

I never tried it without the Blichman Beer Gun, but after using the gun, it seems that would need to use something like that. I split the cost with a friend, since you only need it sporadically.

It's a bummer to spend money on something that doesn't actually make beer, but it's been a great investment. I buy seasonal commercial kegs and transfer the entire keg to bottles so I can have the beer I like and not take up a spot in the keg fridge.